# Git tag status while not in directory

Tags: git, shell, tags, status

I am working on a project, where I am trying to see all tags while I am not in the directory. I see that it's possible to commit or push, but is it also possible to list the tags while you are not in the directory?

This command didn't work:

```
cd mln/projects/test/projectx-test/; git tag show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a git command from any folder, you could simply add the path to the repo:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git tag
```

(`git tag show` does not exist as a git command: see [`git tag` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag))

Comment: @user3270211 just use "`git tag`", `git tag show` does not exist) I have updated the answer.